Share local ubuntu server 24.04 LTS proxy with other devices on the home network via v2ray
Here is my desired setup:
Home Ubuntu 24.04 LTS server IP: 192.168.1.110
(A) Home Lan devices using v2ray client using socks5 --> (B) V2ray server running on local ubuntu server port 1080 --> (C) local ubuntu server port 8086 --> (D) Cloudflare proxy
I would like to pass home network traffic of my lan devices through cloudflare proxy using socks5 protocol. From point B to D everything works but I can't figure out point A to B. NO firewall is configured on home server yet. Thanks
NOTE
On ubuntu desktop with nekoray gui installed, I can achieve this by creating a socks5 connection and then check "" Allow other devices to connect" option. This way, any device on my home network can use the proxy via v2ray client. I'm trying to use ubuntu server instead and get the same result.
Here is my settings:
V2ray config file
{ "inbounds": \[ { "port": 1080, "listen": "0.0.0.0", "protocol": "socks", "settings": { "auth": "noauth", "udp": false, "ip": "0.0.0.0" } } \], "outbounds": \[ { "protocol": "socks", "settings": { "servers": \[ { "address": "127.0.0.1", "port": 8086 } \] } } \] }

Enabled IP Forwarding
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
nano /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
Applied
sudo sysctl -p
Iptables Rules
Add iptables rules to allow traffic on port 1080
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1080 -j ACCEPT sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 1080 -j ACCEPT sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1080 -j DNAT --to-destination` [`0.0.0.0:1080`](http://0.0.0.0:1080)
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

Persist after a reboot
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu being used.

According to this doc you can not do this the way you are trying. https://www.cand.uscourts.gov/2018/02/v2ray-a-comprehensive-guide-to-setting-up-your-own-private-vpn-account/#:~:text=V2Ray%20is%20a%20VPN%20service,users%20protect%20their%20online%20privacy.

@DavidDE addedd ubuntu version

@DavidDE on ubuntu desktop you can achieve this using nekoray gui and check "allow other devices to connect" option, however don't know how to do it in ubuntu server.

If your server and Home Lan device are on the same network, then you don't need IP forwarding.
First, remove all the IP table rules to remove any chance of those interfering, and then use this configuration for V2ray on your server:
{
    "inbounds": [
      {
        "port": 1080, // Listening port of the server
        "protocol": "socks", 
        "sniffing": {
          "enabled": true,
          "destOverride": ["http", "tls"]
        },
        "settings": {
          "auth": "noauth"  
        }
      }
    ],
    "outbounds": [
      {
        "protocol": "socks",
        "settings": {
            "servers": [{
                "address": "127.0.0.1",
                "port": 8086 // Outbound to the VPN
            }],
              "auth": "noauth"
        }
      }
    ]
  }

This will make the server's V2ray listen on port 1080 and reroute the data to port 8086 both using the socks protocol.
Then in order to connect your client, the Home Lan, to this server, use the following configuration in the Home Lab's V2ray:
{
    "inbounds": [
      {
        "port": 1080, // Listening port of the client.(for applications)
        "protocol": "socks", 
        "sniffing": {
          "enabled": true,
          "destOverride": ["http", "tls"]
        },
        "settings": {
          "auth": "noauth"  
        }
      }
    ],
    "outbounds": [
      {
        "protocol": "socks",
        "settings": {
            "servers": [{
                "address": "192.168.1.110", // Route data to the Ubuntu server address
                "port": 1080 // Listening port of the server
            }],
              "auth": "noauth"
        }
      }
    ]
  }

This will listen on port 1080 of the Home Lab (for applications to send v2ray their data) and routes all the data to the IP address and port of the server, those being 192.168.1.110 and port 1080.
You can also save the configurations to a file and run the following command to check if they are correct:
v2ray test -c <path/to/config/file.json>
If they are correct you'll see an output similar to this:
v2ray test -c server.json
V2Ray 5.16.1 (V2Fly, a community-driven edition of V2Ray.) Custom (go1.22.2 linux/amd64)
A unified platform for anti-censorship.
Configuration OK.

